Run DXL script with existing instance of DOORS without login
I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to run a DXL script using an existing instance of DOORS. That is, I know how to run it from the command line with the username and password parameter, and I don't want to provide those but rather force the user to login into an instance of DOORS, and use that instance to run some DXL code from a different application. Does the command line support using an existing instance of DOORS without the username/password parameters?

In pure doors.exe + DXL it is not possible, but you can use OLE Automation to connect to existing DOORS instances. https://jazz.net/dxl/html/1844%20-%20Invoke%20DOORS%20%20from%20external%20Application%20with%20OLE%20Automation.html might give you some ideas about advantages, disadvantages, usage and alternatives.
